# Extracting some part of text from a tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<a title="Home" href="#">Home<br>test</a>
<a title="Home" href="#">Home two<br>test</a>
<a title="Home" href="#">Home two three<br>test</a>
```

What I need is to get the text "Home" and "Home two" and "Home two three" from the address tags. I had forgotten that I can have a br tag in between.

I need something like this:

```
var abc = a.html()
```

but I know this only gives me everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; }).first().text()` to get the first text node value. This will throw out any text after that (like your `br` and on). Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cHhU5/

Comment: is there a way I could code this using something like a.html() which is what I'm replacing?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. So you want to get the first text node of each link distinctly? You can do something like `$('a').each(function() { var abc = $(this).contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; }).first().text(); alert(abc); });`. This will alert the first text node of each anchor individually.

Answer (score 0):

Hiya **simple demo** (new updated for your specific case) http://jsfiddle.net/zrmGm/

http://jsfiddle.net/XswN4/ **And** demo when you can have 3 words and it will still pick up 2 http://jsfiddle.net/XswN4/1/

**Updated demo** based on what yo unmentioned this will help http://jsfiddle.net/zrmGm/ (this sample will get youi everything before `<br>` tag!

using `match` further read: http://www.jquery4u.com/syntax/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples/

**code**

```
$.fn.ready(function() {

    $('a').each(function() {

        var str = $(this).html().match(/\w+\s\w+/);

        alert(str);
    });

});​
```

**Updated code** to get everything before `<br>` tag

```
$.fn.ready(function() {

    $('a').each(function() {

        var str = $(this).html().split('<br>')[0]

        alert(str);
    });

});​
```

Comment: Hello. Can you in a couple of lines explain the match for me. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hiya @MarieJ yep sure gimme 2, cheerios

Comment: Tats. I am sorry. I realize it doesn't pick out where there are more than one or two words. Can you have a quick look at the question again. Thanks.

Comment: Hiya @MarieJ here you exactly what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/zrmGm/ this will help you :) updating my answer, cherrios!